# Unable to Locate New Post button in blogger

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to automate blog posting using selenium and python

Able to locate element using Inspect element in browser

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys



browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.blogger.com/go/signin')
email = browser.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
email.send_keys("xxxxxx@gmail.com")
email.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
password.send_keys("xxxxxx")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)

newpost = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("editor")

posttitle = browser.find_element_by_name("K3JSBVB-C-b titleField textField K3JSBVB-C-a")
```

error

Unable to locate element: [name="K3JSBVB-C-b titleField textField K3JSBVB-C-a"]

Answer (score 0):

This `K3JSBVB-C-b` [class attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_class.asp) looks dynamic, I would rather suggest sticking to the `New post` text instead.

The relevant XPath expression would be something like:

```
//a[text()='New post']
```

[image]

Also consider using [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) as using sleep is an [antipattern you should be avoiding](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43807/the-worst-anti-patterns-you-have-came-across)

```
new_post = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH("//a[text()='New post']")))
new_post.click()
```

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)